# Grafana transform data such that data belonging together is grouped in rows

Tags: visualization, grafana

I have a database storing subtasks looking like this:

```
{
    "task_id":1,
    "subtask_name":"preparation",
    "subtask_status":"done"
}
```

Each task consists of two subtasks, the preparation and the realization. I now have a Grafana table that looks like this:

| task_id | subtask_name | subtask_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | preparation | done |
| 1 | realization | tbd |
| 2 | preparation | tbd |
| 2 | realization | tbd |

and want to group the subtasks together to their corresponding tasks, so that it looks like this:

| task_id | preparation | realization |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | done | tbd |
| 2 | tbd | tbd |

which Grafana Transformations do I have to use to achieve that result? I use elasticsearch as a database. Do I need to group the data with a Lucene query?

Comment: Sounds like a task for classical pivot, and usually this task is way better handled by DBMS than Grafana. But I'm not sure if it's true for elastic.

Comment: On Grafana's side you can do it but introducing two separate queries: for preparation rows, and for realization rows, and the joining them.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you help me a little with how those querys would have to look like? I am very new to Lucene so I am really struggling with that.

Comment: I'm not Lucene guy either. But for two separate queries, as in my second comment, I believe your query would look something like this `subtask_name:preparation`